# Why is ViewController's initial orientation is not landscape when it should be?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I'm making an app that only supports landscape mode of an iOS device. So I have set it to only return YES for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and set the initial orientation in `Info.plist` to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. The app is displaying fine.

The problem is that the coordinate system is not in landscape until the view is finished loading (I'm not particularly sure here when it is being applied correctly). What I know is that it changes to the correct coordinate space when it calls the: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` upon launch. The problem is that when both `viewDidLoad` and `initWithCoder:` are called it is in the wrong coordinate space, before `shouldAutorotate...`.

What I mean is that if I set a view to the full width of the screen with `CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)` (instead of using self.view.frame or something) it is borked when the coordinate spaces are rotated "corrected". The views created in `viewDidLoad` have a rotation applied to them so they are wrong. This makes setting up views in those methods a pain and really illogical. I'm guessing that this is an issue with how orientations are handled. Why does it behave like this? I have told it in every way possible that I only want landscape position. Can this be something with Interface builder and properties there?

This is using a standard `UIViewController`. The new views are however also loaded from .xib files in `viewDidLoad`. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for orientation changes is something that *all* iOS developers struggle with at one time or another. It's often confusing and frustrating. Here's a rule of thumb which will handle 95% of all orientation issues:

> Orientation related interface changes (such as frame resizing) don't happen until `viewWillAppear:`. Until then, your view will be in portrait mode **even if you only support landscape in your app or your app is already in landscape mode**.

Since `viewDidLoad:` occurs before `viewWillAppear:`, orientation layout changes haven't occured yet. So, doing any of the following in `viewDidLoad` will often have wonky results (depending on how the view's autoResize is set):

- inserting a layer (such as a gradient) inside a view with a frame that is equal to the view's bounds. The layer inserted will always be the size of the view in portrait mode. If that view stretches when rotating to landscape view, your layer will be smaller than the view.
- trying to determine the size of a table view and using that frame for some other view
- manually adding a child view controller and using a container view's frame to determine the child view controller's view frame.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. Great rule of thumb.

Comment: For anyone else coming to this, I found this not to work. I had to update my subviews during the viewDidAppear stage. It might be particular to my case. I'm setting orientation in my AppDelegate.supportedOrientationsFor.

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading over the `UIViewController` documentation today, and I remember reading about this.

From the “Handling View Rotations” overview section:

> By default, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode only. To support additional orientations, you must override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method and return YES for any orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing properties of your views are configured correctly, that may be all you have to do. However, the UIViewController class provides additional hooks for you to implement additional behaviors as needed.
>
> …
>
> **Note: At launch time, applications should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation**. After the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method returns, the application uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57

One thing I can think of that might be causing you extra trouble is if you’re setting `autoresizingMask` options on your subviews. Could make predicting what will happen when the view is rotated and resized very difficult if all your numbers are wrong.

If you're using custom UIVIews, you might want to override `layoutSubviews:` to handle the different times when it may be necessary to layout the subviews again (or when you call `setNeedsLayout`).

Comment: Thanks for this insightful comment. I'm animating the views before the rotation check by iOS, so maybe this could be stirring the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the Supported interface orientations in [project]-info.plist file, set item 0 value to Landscape (right home button).

Comment: I still have this problem even though the only supported interface orientation in my Info.plist is "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight". Which in my opinion, is quite odd.